# Creating a desktop icon using JWS JNLP without codebase

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I have my .jnlp and jar file on my desktop and it creates a shortcut. If I specify the codebase it even sets the image.

I have removed the codebase and If no codebase is specified, the Java Web Start software assumes that the codebase is relative to the web page from which the Java Web Start application is launched. So if i place the icon on the desktop it sets the image to my shortcut. But is there a way so that i can refer to the jar file, where i have my icon, so that it can set the image to the shortcut created?

Comment: *"Java Web Start software assumes that the codebase is relative to the web page from which the Java Web Start application is launched"*  Only for an applet, and only if it starts embedded in the page.  Are you launching an applet?

Comment: yes, I am launching an applet and providing the url's to launch the application in web browser.